# Bash script copy remote directory to local directory only updates file

Tags: scp

I want to remote directory to local directory.script works properly but I have face some issue every time SCP update all files. My use case only updated file is copy the remote directory to local directory. if any bash gem helps appreciated your efforts. The source code is attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R58uB.png).

Comment: Please rephrase you question as I don't get what you are saying and don't images but copy and paste the the texts from the terminal

Comment: I've suggested an edit that takes care of the above.

Comment: Please elaborate on the following: You make a local directory with the current date. When you want to update files from remote to local, is it "per day", or should it compare today with the files from yesterday, and only copy updated?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the only update file for the last day backup Date directory. Compare or something else solution no issue I want the only updated file, not every file override. The date is just the directory name.

Comment: @ArturMeinild you are right current date the just local directory name. the second question yes, compare file only update file is copy update.

Comment: If the directory name didn't change, you could use rsync. If you want a new directory every day, you have compare the files from remote and yesterday first.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#-- start config
# Local Directory for backups. A date-specific folder is created under this directory for the files.
LD=/home/ec2-user/newFolder

# Remote Directory to retrieve. Files are retrieved recursively starting here. Hidden files are included.
# Must be full path, don't use ~ shortcut.
RD=/home/ec2-user/new
# Path to SSH ID file (private key)
ID=~/.ssh/id_rsa

DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# USERname to login as
USER=user-name
# HOST to login to
HOST=host-name
#--- end config
 
BD="$LD/$DATE"
mkdir $BD
scp -ri $ID $USER@$HOST:$RD $BD

Comment: @ArturMeinild kindly provide the compare bash script.

Comment: I was hoping someone else could do that, I have my hands full right now, sorry.